# node.appendChild not behaving as expected in <=IE9 (haven't checked 10)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Im having a really weird IE problem that I can't figure out what the root cause is.  I'm hoping to get an explanation as to what internally is going wrong. I can append a dynamically created element to another once, but any subsequent attempts to append the node removes any children appended to it.

I have a function create a wrapper div, and then appends a child 'p' with some text attached to it.  Function essentially reads like this:

```
function buildElement(text){
  var node,p,doc = document;
  node = doc.createElement('div');
  node.setAttribute('class','node-wrapper');

  p = doc.createElement('p');
  p.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(text));

  node.appendChild(p);
  return node;
}
```

It's pretty straight forward.  This builds an element that contains the text that you pass into it.  Heres a scaled down version of what I'm trying to do, and comments to describe what's happening in IE:

```
// create a parent wrapper element
var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.setAttribute('class','parent-wrapper');

var childNode = buildElement('This is a sample');

// This will append a child node with all of its children, 
// everything works as expected - ex:
// <div class="parent-wrapper">
//   <div class="node-wrapper">
//     <p>This is a sample</p>
//   </div>
// </div>
wrapper.appendChild(childNode);

// empty the parent wrapper
wrapper.innerHTML = '';

// re-append the childNode element to the parent wrapper
// in IE, this step will fill the parent node with just the node-wrapper element
// with the removed child node(s) - ex:
// <div class="parent-wrapper">
//   <div class="node-wrapper" />
// </div>
wrapper.appendChild(childNode);
```

What you'll see if you run this, is that the first `wrapper.appendChild(childNode)` works great and as expected.  But the second attempt to append the child node will result in the childNode's children being removed from the childNode. (ex: the 'p' is gone.);
You can see a working example of this here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jiggliemon/52ZPR/

What's weird is that you can avoid the child-node removal by not appending the childNode, but appending a Clone of the child node `wrapper.appendChild(childNode.cloneNode(true))`.
You can see a working example of this here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jiggliemon/52ZPR/3/

Here is a more elaborate example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jiggliemon/bcSpQ/

Comment: `p.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(text));` => `p.textContent = text`. it's the "same" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wrapper.innerHTML = ''`

seems to damage your inner nodes. Don't use it. The correct technique is

```
for (var i = 0, len = wrapper.childNodes; i < len; i++) {
  wrapper.removeChild(wrapper.childNodes[i]);
}
```

This should fix your bug.

However other then saying `innerHTML` is bad! I can't explain your bug.

The [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#dom-innerhtml) says :

> Remove the child nodes of the node whose innerHTML attribute is being set, firing appropriate mutation events.

So it really should not be damaging `childNode`

As a side-note:

`p.textContent = text;`

is the "same" as

`p.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(text));`

As a further aside the idea that

`x.innerHTML = ''`

is a *fast* way to empty x is a *lie*.

[Benchmark](http://jsperf.com/textcontent-vs-innerhtml12/2)

Please use a while loop over the firstChild or set `.textContent = ''`

Comment: This upsets me greatly.  Why would IE do such a thing?  This solved my problem, however I'd still like to get an explanation about Why it's doing what it's doing.

Comment: @Chase if I had an IE9 machine to test I would tell you (XP hates IE9). I assume it's IE9's `innerHTML` implementation removing "descendants" recursively or something. Really though don't use `.innerHTML`, ever.

Comment: Point taken.  I just used it since it's would appear to be faster than  looping through child elements.  But consistency is obviously more important Thankyou.  And F-you MS.

Comment: `innerHTML` has its uses (for example, concisely and readably creating simple DOM nodes, or concisely removing all children of an existing element). I disagree with @Raynos that you should never use it.

Comment: @TimDown DOM API's are better for conciseness and readability, inline HTML is a nightmare. However concisely removing all children would be a great use case if IE9 wasn't bugged.

Comment: @Raynos: I'd prefer `el.innerHTML = "<b>cheese</b> and <i>jam</i><br>sandwich"` over the alternative using three `document.createElement()`s and four `document.createTextNode()`s for both brevity and clarity, unless I needed to keep references to the nodes being created.

Comment: @TimDown Actually after making a [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/textcontent-vs-innerhtml12/2) I realised that `.innerHTML = ''` is slow and should be avoided. I'll say it again never use it.

Comment: @TimDown agreed, that innerHTML statement is nicer, but when do we actually want to write something like that? it's a contrived example, there is no proper use-case, the proper solutions are using some kind of templating system to abstract it for you with it's own HTML parser (or `.innerHTML` hacks)

Comment: @Raynos: Fair enough. My opinion isn't very different to yours, but I still feel `innerHTML` is useful. I'll give you three of my real use cases: 1) getting IE version using conditional comments: `div.innerHTML = "<!--[if lte IE 6]><i></i><![endif]-->"; var isIe6 = !!div.getElementsByTagName("i").length`. I use this for detecting IE 6's PNG transparency problem since no viable feature test exists. 2) `el.innerHTML = "";`. This is still fine if you don't need the inner nodes any more. 3) Debugging/logging. It's often convenient to log the inner HTML of an element: `log.debug(el.innerHTML);`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4461/discussion-between-raynos-and-tim-down)

Comment: textContent seems to suck in IE as well.